# How do I set a DB2_SCROLLABLE with hold in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, db2

I've been working on creating an object oriented database call class for practice and I've been trying to figure out how to incorporate a scrollable cursor properly. I would like to be able to call this function in order to grab the next 10 records or a different function for the previous 10 records. I've gotten to the point where I can specify an offset for the records through the scrollable cursor but I cannot call the same function again to get the next set without passing in an incremented offset value.

How would I go about being able to specify a number of records per page and simply call getNextSet() or getPrevSet() in order to get the results I want.

My current line of thinking is setting a static variable somewhere and incrementing/deincrementing or resetting it accordingly then use that as the offset value in the functions. However, I believe I heard there was an issue with using static variables in instantiated classes.

Here's the code so far:

```
<?php
$i5DBconn = db2_connect("*LOCAL", "", "");
if (!$i5DBconn) {
echo "Database Connection failed. SQL Err:";
echo db2_conn_error();
echo "<br>";
echo db2_conn_errormsg();

die();
} 
class queryDB{
    var $query;
    var $outputFunction;
    var $parameters;

    function performDBCall(){
        global $i5DBconn;
        $dbStatement = db2_prepare($i5DBconn, $this->query, array('cursor' => DB2_SCROLLABLE));
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($this->parameters as $param) {
            db2_bind_param($dbStatement, $i, 'param', DB2_PARAM_IN);
            $i++;
        }

        $result = db2_execute($dbStatement);
        if (!$result){
            echo "$this->query failed!. ";
            echo 'SQLSTATE value: ' . db2_stmt_error();
            echo ' Message: ' .   db2_stmt_errormsg();
        }
        return $dbStatement;
    }
}

class invoiceCall extends queryDB {
    function testQueryFormatter($dbResultSet, $dataOffset){
    $zebraStriping = 1;
?>
//snipped header row formatting
<?php
    $rowLimit = 10;
    while(($rowData = db2_fetch_array($dbResultSet, $dataOffset)) && ($zebraStriping < $rowLimit)){
        list($dataNames) = $rowData;
        ?>
        //snipped data formatting
        <?php 
        $dataOffset++;
    }
}
}
$offsetVal = 5;
$testQuery = new invoiceCall();
$testQuery->query = "select invoice#, status, amountpaid, amountbilled,  invoicedate, paydate, custname, termofpay, balance from TESTSCHEMA.SAMPLE_INVOICE_TABLE";
//$testQuery->parameters = [8000001];
$resultSet = $testQuery->performDBCall();
$testQuery->testQueryFormatter($resultSet, $offsetVal);
?>
```

If there are also some coding practices I could improve on, let me know as I am starting my first real journey into Object Oriented PHP.

Comment: you don't need a static variable, just an attribute in your db class, e.g. `$dbobj->offset = 42`. as long as you don't re-use that offset value for multiple queries, you should be fine.

Comment: So, for example, I would set the offset value to 0 for an instance of the devTool class then just add or remove from that property when I call getNextSet()/getPrevSet()?